# mwc-icon 0.7.1 not rendering (with lit-element/pwa-starter-kit)?

Tags: lit-element, pwa-starter-kit

Has any one got mwc-icon (0.7.1) to work with lit-element (pwa-starter-kit)?

mwc-button renders OK but mwc-icon does not render the icon just the icon index text.

```
import { html } from 'lit-element';
import { PageViewElement } from './page-view-element.js';
import {Icon} from "@material/mwc-icon" //does not work
import {Button} from "@material/mwc-button"

import { SharedStyles } from './shared-styles.js';

class MyView1 extends PageViewElement {
  static get styles() {
    return [
      SharedStyles
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <section>
        <h2>Example</h2>
        <mwc-icon>bookmark</mwc-icon>
        <mwc-button outlined label="outlined"></mwc-button>
    `;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('my-view1', MyView1);
```

Comment: did you slve this pb ? I don t succeed to render ligature inside litelement render's method ?

Comment: The problem is still open.

Answer (score 2):

I think you encounter the same problem I did.

It happens because Chrome process the @font-face attribute only once at first page load.

when you import the mwc styles you expect them to enable in the lit-element render - after the first initial load of the page. that will work, you'll see the new styles **except for the @font-face attribute.**

That's why you don't see the icon.

*A quick workaround is to append the link both on the head section in
index.html **and** in the lit-element as you did.*

you can see [example that don't work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xgh95b)
and [example that work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2blvnd)

The difference is the added link in index.html head section.

---

More details here: [github thread](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/809)

Hope I helped you with this.
I was stuck on it myself for quite some time